# How to force ScrollView children onMeasure?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-scrollview

In view hierarchy:

- `ViewParent > ScrollView > LinearLayout`

When dimensions change, `ViewParent.onMeasure` calls `ScrollView.onMeasure` witch calls `LinearLayout.onMeasure` only if `ScrollView.width` have changed, what seems normal because `LinearLayout` is only constrained by his parent **width**.

How to force `LinearLayout.onMeasure`, also if `ScrollView.width` not changed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The solution**

override `ScrollView.onMeasure` and add `LinearLayout.forceLayout` call:

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int wMS, int hMS) {
    if (getChildCount() > 0)
        getChildAt(0).forceLayout();
    super.onMeasure(wMS, hMS);
}
```